# How can I boot an Intel Core i7 iMac in 64-bit mode?

Tags: macos, imac, 64-bit

I have an iMac running OS X 10.6.8. The processor is a 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 and the machine has 4 GB of RAM. How can I boot the computer in 64-bit mode (instead of 32-bit mode) so that I can upgrade to OS X 10.9 and run Final Cut Pro 10.3?

Answer (score 6):

To start up with a special kernel check this from Apple: [Starting up with the 32-bit or 64-bit kernel in 10.6 and later](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3773):

> **Startup key combination (for current startup only)**
>
> If your Mac uses the 32-bit kernel by default, but supports the 64-bit
>   kernel, you can start up using the 64-bit kernel by holding the
>   <kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>4</kbd> keys during startup.
>
> If your Mac uses the 64-bit kernel by default, you can start up with
>   the 32-bit kernel by holding the <kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> keys
>   during startup.
>
> Your Mac will revert to the default kernel the next time you reboot
>   it.
>
> **On-disk setting (persistent)**
>
> To select the 64-bit kernel for the current startup disk, use the
>   following command in Terminal:
>
> `sudo systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture x86_64`
>
> To select the 32-bit kernel for the current startup disk, use the
>   following command in Terminal:
>
> `sudo systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture i386`
>
> Note: This setting is stored in the
>   `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist` file
>   and will take effect every time you start up from this disk. If you
>   start up from a different disk, the setting on that disk, or the
>   hardware default, will take effect.

To determine your currently running kernel open `Terminal.app` and enter:
`uname -a`
Running with the 64-bit kernel, the output will end with `RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`. Running with the 32-bit kernel, the output will end with `RELEASE_I386 i386`.

In your case you just have to update to Mavericks (Mac OS X 10.9). Mavericks doesn't contain a 32-bit kernel anymore and since your i7-processor is 64-bit, everything just works right out of the box without key strokes or modifying `com.apple.Boot.plist`.